# Accessing Table with synonym instead of table name with Spring JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have used Spring JPA in my project.
Following is my POJO class:

```
@Table (name="CustomerSys")
class Customer implements Serializable {
/* Fields defined here */
}
```

In my database, there is a table exists with name Customer but to access that table we have created a synonym with name CustomerSys. Now when i execute my code it throwing an error says:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

Can you please help me to know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application I have used two difference data sources. I debugg the the application and found that the incorrect data sources mapped due to this table or view does't exits appears. So,
 1. I correct the mapping first, then a error msg appears with name incorrect protocol found.
 2. Then I used ojdbc6 instead of ojdbc14.

This made my application working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hibernate 4.3 or later, you can add `hibernate.synonyms=true` to your persistence configuration.

Comment: Have you tried adding `hibernate.connection.includeSynonyms=true` as well?

Comment: I have added both the property as:
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "");
        
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.includeSynonyms", true);
But still the result is same