# Synonyms views and tables in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, synonym

Using jpql, I used:

- `createQuery` with **Tables**.
- `createNativeQuery` with **Views**.

Could you please tell me what I have to use with synonyms `createQuery` or `createNativeQuery` ?.
I found a problem with data stored in synonyms (oracle) when running my spring-mvc project..

Big thanks.

Comment: Link to your previous related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076369/synonym-emptied-after-run-java-project

Comment: Sorry Sir @Kayaman about that, but I couldn't succeed to resolve my problem. I need to made changes on the synonym without deleting its data after running the project. 
Indeed, the property  `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>` have to still in the file `persistence.xml`

Comment: There's no rule about JPQL queries being used for tables and native queries for views. You can map a view to an entity as well, although it'll be read only.

Comment: As for your root issue. Your `update` will drop those synonyms, so either get rid of the synonyms or get rid of the `update`. Or upgrade your library versions, but I seem to recall that you can't do that either.

Comment: Big thanks Sir @Kayaman about your Kindness. So as you prove, my problem cannot be solved although the upgrade to hibernate 5.4.
In that case, using table is the solution. Thanks again Sir.

Comment: Alright. Well, I'm glad I could give you some help with this. Apparently you need [Version 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623343/accessing-table-with-synonym-instead-of-table-name-with-spring-jpa) or later for the `synonyms` property to work.

Comment: That is it Sir @Kayaman, As YOU SAW, using Hibernate 4.3 or later, I can made changes on the synonym without deleting its data after running my project while retaining the property `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>` in the file `persistence.xml`. Big Big thanks Sir.

Comment: If you do not mind Sir, could you please make it as **answer**, So then I can made it as THE CORRECT ANSWER. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original support for synonyms for Oracle and other RDBMses was introduced at a point I can't determine exactly. I suppose even Hibernate 3 had some support for them with the `hibernate.synonyms=true` property.

Still, there are a few synonym related bugs, such as `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` not working before [4.2.1](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8183) and fixing that with `hibernate.connection.includeSynonyms=true`.

Since the behaviour of `validate` and `update` are related (they both need to understand synonyms), I assume that the *minimum* version you need to upgrade to solve your problem would be `4.2.1`.

Comment: Big Thanks Sir @Kayaman for your help. That will be also the detailed answer of the thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076369/synonym-emptied-after-run-java-project).

Comment: @Linda I'll link that as a duplicate here.

Comment: Ok Sir @Kayaman, I'll delete the first one to respect the stack overflow community terms. Big thanks Sir for your Kindness.